# How to create a boost::histogram as a class member and initialize it in the class constructor?

Tags: c++, boost, histogram

It's not clear how to create a `boost::histogram` object as a class member and initialize it in the class constructor using `boost::histogram::make_histogram()`, given that the return type of `make_histogram()` is heavily templated.

The [Getting Started](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/libs/histogram/doc/html/histogram/getting_started.html#histogram.getting_started.making_classes_that_hold_histogr) guide gives an example of using a wrapper struct as follows:

```cpp
struct HolderOfStaticHistogram {
    using axes_t = std::tuple<
        boost::histogram::axis::regular<>,
        boost::histogram::axis::integer<>
    >;
    using hist_t = boost::histogram::histogram<axes_t>;
    hist_t hist_;
};

int main() {
    using namespace boost::histogram;

    HolderOfStaticHistogram hs;
    hs.hist_ = make_histogram(axis::regular<>(5, 0, 1), axis::integer<>(0, 3));
}
```

However, putting `make_histogram` in the constructor doesn't compile, for example:

```cpp
struct HolderOfStaticHistogram {
    using axes_t = boost::histogram::axis::regular<>;
    using hist_t = boost::histogram::histogram<axes_t>;
    hist_t hist_;

    HolderOfStaticHistogram() {
        hist_ = boost::histogram::make_histogram(
            boost::histogram::axis::regular<>(5, 0, 1));
    }
};

int main() {
    auto hist_container = HolderOfStaticHistogram();
}
```

```
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_80_0/boost/histogram/detail/axes.hpp:310:5: error: no member named 'resize' in 'boost::histogram::axis::regular<double, boost::use_default, boost::use_default, boost::use_default>'
  t.resize(sizeof...(Us));
  ~ ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_80_0/boost/histogram/histogram.hpp:98:13: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::histogram::detail::axes_assign<boost::histogram::axis::regular<double, boost::use_default, boost::use_default, boost::use_default>, boost::histogram::axis::regular<double, boost::use_default, boost::use_default, boost::use_default> >' requested here
    detail::axes_assign(axes_, std::move(unsafe_access::axes(rhs)));
            ^
<source>:53:15: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::histogram::histogram<boost::histogram::axis::regular<double, boost::use_default, boost::use_default, boost::use_default>, boost::histogram::unlimited_storage<std::allocator<char> > >::operator=<std::tuple<boost::histogram::axis::regular<double, boost::use_default, boost::use_default, boost::use_default> >, boost::histogram::unlimited_storage<std::allocator<char> > >' requested here
        hist_ = boost::histogram::make_histogram(
```

One workaround is to use `decltype` on the expression that calls `make_histogram` as follow:

```cpp
#include <boost/histogram.hpp>

class HistContainer {
public:
    using axis_t = boost::histogram::axis::regular<>;
    using hist_t = decltype(boost::histogram::make_histogram(axis_t(10, 0, 10)));
    hist_t hist;

    HistContainer() {
        hist = boost::histogram::make_histogram(axis_t(10, 0, 10));
    }
};

int main() {
    auto hist_container = HistContainer();
}
```

However, this is not ideal since we have to construct the `histogram` object twice. What is the correct way to have a `boost::histogram` as a class member?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a missing tuple:

```
using axes_t = std::tuple<boost::histogram::axis::regular<> >;
```

And also, use base/member initializer lists:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77f17a46bbe1b0a1)**

```cpp
#include <boost/histogram.hpp>
namespace bh = boost::histogram;

struct HolderOfStaticHistogram {
    using axes_t = std::tuple<bh::axis::regular<>>;
    using hist_t = bh::histogram<axes_t>;
    hist_t hist_;

    HolderOfStaticHistogram() : hist_{bh::make_histogram(bh::axis::regular<>(5, 0, 1))} {}
};

int main() {
    auto hist_container = HolderOfStaticHistogram();
}
```